# Could not get any response after deploying to the service in google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using google app engine for nodejs application deployment using
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app doc.
my nodejs version is v10.14.2
and npm version is 6.14.8
port is 4000,
export port using "export PORT=4000".

NOTE: could not get any response at the end it says network error.

Basically I made an instance and setup compute engine there and deployed it. It is working now, I am made app engine in the same project. so, I have deployed two instances on same project one(compute engine) is working and other(app engine) is not